# JavaScript array looping over getting an error if array has mulitple data types

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

'''

```
const temperatures = ['error',3, -2, -6, -1, 'error', 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitide = function (temp) {
  let maxTemp = temp[0];
  let minTemp = temp[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    const current_temp = temp[i];
    if (typeof current_temp !== 'number') continue;

    if (current_temp > maxTemp) maxTemp = current_temp;
    if (current_temp < minTemp) minTemp = current_temp;
  }

  return maxTemp - minTemp;
};
const amplitude = calcTempAmplitide(temperatures);

console.log(amplitude);
```

'''

After running this in Visual code I am getting a NaN value
if I remove 'error' from the beginning then the code works
Any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

```
let maxTemp = temp[0];
let minTemp = temp[0];
```

means that if the array doesn't start with a number, comparisons won't make sense (and subtraction at the end won't work either).

How about filtering the array to remove non-numbers first?

```js
const temperatures = ['error',3, -2, -6, -1, 'error', 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitide = function (temp) {
  const nums = temp.filter(val => typeof val === 'number');
  let maxTemp = nums[0];
  let minTemp = nums[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const current_temp = nums[i];
    if (current_temp > maxTemp) maxTemp = current_temp;
    if (current_temp < minTemp) minTemp = current_temp;
  }

  return maxTemp - minTemp;
};
const amplitude = calcTempAmplitide(temperatures);

console.log(amplitude);
```

or

```js
const temperatures = ['error',3, -2, -6, -1, 'error', 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitide = function (temp) {
  const nums = temp.filter(val => typeof val === 'number');
  return Math.max(...nums) - Math.min(...nums);
};
const amplitude = calcTempAmplitide(temperatures);

console.log(amplitude);
```